# Custom Bootstrap custom popover won't hide or execute buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, popover

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and I have a custom popover with a textarea and "ok" and "cancel" buttons. The popover displays correctly when the anchor is clicked, however the buttons in the popover won't execute. I'm also using Kendo UI if that helps.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="popover" id="memo" 
  class="btn btn-default" title="Special instructions" href="#">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
  Special Instructions
</a>

    <style>
        .popover-content {
           height: 180px;  
           width: 200px;  
        }

        textarea.popover-textarea {
           border: 0px;   
           margin: 0px; 
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           padding: 0px;  
           box-shadow: none;
        }

        .popover-footer {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 8px 14px;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 400;
          line-height: 18px;
          background-color: #F7F7F7;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
          border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

    </style>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#memo").popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
    template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
              '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content">' +
              '</div><div class="popover-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary popover-submit">' +
              '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>&nbsp;' +
              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default popover-cancel">' +
              '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div></div>'
})
.on('shown', function() {

    $('#memo').not(this).popover("hide");
    var $this = $(this);

    //attach the specialInstructions variable to the text
    $('.popover-textarea #memo').val((specialInstructions == null) ? '' : specialInstructions).focus();

    $('.popover-textarea #memo').val("testing").focus();

    // close on cancel
    $('.popover-cancel #memo').click(function() {
        $("#memo").popover('hide');
    });

    $('.popover-submit #memo').click(function() {
        specialInstructions = $('.popover-textarea').val();
        $("#memo").popover('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your buttons are added dynamically, try something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.popover-cancel #memo', function() {
    $("#memo").popover('hide');
});

$(document).on('click', '.popover-submit #memo', function() {
    specialInstructions = $('.popover-textarea').val();
    $("#memo").popover('hide');
});
```

instead of

```
$('.popover-cancel #memo').click(function() {
    $("#memo").popover('hide');
});

$('.popover-submit #memo').click(function() {
    specialInstructions = $('.popover-textarea').val();
    $("#memo").popover('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In most of the examples the event handler `shown` is fired when the popover has been made visible to the user. Upon examining the documentation, the newest version of Bootstrap uses the event handler `shown.bs.popover`. Once I changed the event handler in my code everything worked as expected.